Drying oven settings for drying soil samples
For my PhD, I will collect soil samples that need to be dried in drying ovens before being ground and ultimately analysed for their nutrient composition. While drying, the samples will be weighted daily until the difference in weight between the current day and the day before is less than 5%. That completes the drying process. The soil samples consist only of litter-free hummus of rendzina type.
I have received the instructions that the samples must be dried at 60°C under exhaust air.
We have two drying ovens, Memmert brand; I don't know the precise model. I can set temperature (°C), time, flap opening (%), and fan speed (%).
I asked my contact person about the flap opening and fan speed settings, but they only suggested that I read the manual. I did, and there is no information on how fan speed and flap opening influence the soil probes. I also don't know what combination of settings achieves exhaust air.
It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could clarify the two points above, highlighted in bold. My background is in nature protection, and I have never worked with soil before.

So if you try out a new oven without precise instructions, you will probably have to experiment yourself. I'd take 3 pots of soil from your garden, make them wet and test them at different settings.
But if you don't have the time, why not put a semi-permeable membrane fine sieve over the sample to prevent the soil from being removed from your sample container if the fan speed is too high?
My own experience of drying deep-sea sediments:
Temperature: 70 degrees
Fan speed: 30-50 %
Flap opening: 30-40 %
Time to get the sample dry: 24 h
